# Struct variables not changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct

I feel like I'm missing something complete obvious so I apologise in advance if (when?) that is the case.
I'm trying to do something really simple, change a bool value in a struct from false to true. Obviously I can't change it directly, so I created a method within the struct that I can call which should change the value there. It doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the code and I'd appreciate any insight;

```
public Dictionary<int, List<ScanLineNode>> allScanLineNodes = new Dictionary<int, List<ScanLineNode>>();

public void MethodName(ScanLineNode node [...])
{       
    //This will perform a raycast from the Node's position in the specified direction. If the raycast hits nothing, it will return Vector3.zero ('Row is complete'), otherwise will return the hit point

    Vector3 terminationPoint = node.RaycastDirection(node, direction, maxDist, targetRaycast, replacementColour, backgroundColour);

    ScanLineNode terminationNode = new ScanLineNode();

    //Previously attempted to store a local reference to this row being used, but also did not work
    //List<ScanLineNode> rowNodes = allScanLineNodes[node.rowNumber];

    [...]

    if (terminationPoint == Vector3.zero)
    {
        //Definitely reaches this point, and executes this function along the row, I have added breakpoints and checked what happens in this for loop. After running 'RowComplete' (which just changes 'rowComplete' from false to true) 'rowComplete' is still false. Just in case I've included the RowComplete() function below.

        Debug.Log("Row Complete: " + node.rowNumber);
        for (int i = 0; i < allScanLineNodes[node.rowNumber].Count; i++)
        {
            allScanLineNodes[node.rowNumber][i].RowCompleted();
        }
    }
}
```

ScanLineNode Struct -- Most stuff is hidden (that I don't believe is affecting this), I have included the RowComplete() function however.

```
public struct ScanLineNode
    {
        [...]
        public bool rowComplete;
        [...]

        public ScanLineNode([...])
        {
            [...]
            rowComplete = false;
            [...]
        }

        public void RowCompleted()
        {
            rowComplete = true;
        }
    }
```

I have also confirmed that RowCOmpleted() does not get called anywhere aside the above location, and 'rowComplete' is only called from the RowComplete() function

Comment: what is `allScanLineNodes[node.rowNumber][i]` ? it *really* matters whether those indexers are on arrays vs lists vs a dictionary for example

Comment: allScanLineNodes is a Dictionary<int, List<ScanLineNode>>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(from comments) `allScanLineNodes is a Dictionary<int, List<ScanLineNode>>`

Right; the indexer for a `List<ScanLineNode>` returns a **copy** of the struct. So when you call the method - you are calling it on a disconnected value on the stack that evaporates a moment later (is overwritten on the stack - this isn't the garbage collector).

This is a common error with mutable structs. Your best bet is probably: don't make mutable structs. But... you could copy it out, mutate it, and then push the mutated value back in:

```
var list = allScanLineNodes[node.rowNumber];
var val = list[i];
val.RowCompleted();
list[i] = val; // push value back in
```

But immutable is usually more reliable.

Note: you *can* get away with this with *arrays*, since the indexer from an array provides access to a *reference* to the in-place struct - rather than a *copy* of the value. But: this isn't a recommendation, as relying on this subtle difference can cause confusion and bugs.

Comment: I thought it was something to do with it being a value type (they still confuse me haha). I've heard immutable/mutable before, but still not 100% certain what it is. With your suggestion, would it be better to, when I Want to change 'RowCompleted', create a new instance of the struct and put that value in? (IE allScanLineNodes[x][y] = new ScanLineNode(........) )

Comment: Saying that though, I've just realised that I use a similar method to change another value (a stored Colour variable) which definitely works. I use a method to change the Color variable based on a color I passed in.

Comment: @NeoKuro and is that color perhaps on a public **field** (not property)? or in an **array** (not list) - that would explain why it works in that case

Comment: @NeoKuro an "immutable" type is one where you can't change the inner values - at all. What you *can* do is create a new similar value with similar values (perhaps with one or two with different values) - and write that different value over the top of the value you want to replace

Comment: as far as I can tell its a regular field, just as the boolean (rowComplete) was. I've now converted all fields to private, and made some of them publicly accessible by a getter property only. When I create a new 'copy' of the struct, with the new data I want (as you said) it seems to work fine. But as I said the Colour field works fine in either case.  I'm also wondering if using the 'ref' keyword was also incorrect? That seemed to cause me issues too (even though rowComplete had changed in the Dictionary, it had not changed in the local 'node' parameter within the method)

Comment: @NeoKuro `rowComplete` was behind a list indexer - it is the list indexer that bit you. Changing to a getter *also* doesn't help - you can use `parent.SomeProperty.RowCompleted();` and it will break in all the same ways :) mutable structs are fun like that, which is why I don't recommend using them - almost all structs should be immutable

Comment: Ah right. I definitely need to learn up more on immutable structs. Do you have any resources/material you could send me (or recommend)? :)